# which file stored os.environ,and store where , disk c: or disk d:

Tags: python, google-app-engine, environment-variables

my code is :

```
os.environ['ss']='ssss'
print os.environ
```

and it show :

```
{'TMP': 'C:\\DOCUME~1\\ADMINI~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp', 'COMPUTERNAME': 'PC-200908062210', 'USERDOMAIN': 'PC-200908062210', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel', 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files', 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '0f02', 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'PATH': 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Program Files\\Hewlett-Packard\\IAM\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Thunder Network\\KanKan\\Codecs;D:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin;d:\\Program Files\\Mercurial\\;D:\\Program Files\\Graphviz2.26.3\\bin;D:\\TDDOWNLOAD\\ok\\gettext\\bin;D:\\Python25;C:\\Program Files\\StormII\\Codec;C:\\Program Files\\StormII;D:\\zjm_code\\;D:\\Python25\\Scripts;D:\\MinGW\\bin;d:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\', 'TEMP': 'C:\\DOCUME~1\\ADMINI~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp', 'BID': '56727834-D5C3-4EBF-BFAA-FA0933E4E721', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'x86', 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users', 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console', 'HOMEPATH': '\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator', 'USERNAME': 'Administrator', 'LOGONSERVER': '\\\\PC-200908062210', 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH', 'CLIENTNAME': 'Console', 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK': 'NO', 'WINDIR': 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Application Data', 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:', 'SS': 'ssss', 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:', 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '2', 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6', 'OS': 'Windows_NT', 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator'}
```

i find google-app-engine set user_id in os.version not in session,look [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/users.py) at line 96-100 and line 257 , and [aeoid](http://github.com/Arachnid/aeoid/blob/master/aeoid/users.py)  at line 177 ,

and i want to know : which file stored os.environ ,and store where , disk c: ,or disk d: ?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly. Do you ask where the file os.environ is located on disk? If yes, the answer is:

There is no such file.

os.environ is a collection of environment variables and informations about the host system, provided by the python interpreter.